# Angular Know what being filtered

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have one ng-repeat filtering searchClient

```
<li ng-repeat="client in Clients | filter:searchClient">
```

And some ng-model | My user will search on one of these filters

```
<input class="input" type="text" ng-model="searchClient.cnpj">
<input class="input" type="text" ng-model="searchClient.name">
<input class="input" type="text" ng-model="searchClient.rz">
```

Depending on the filter that the user is using, I wanna display different pages

My quest is: How do I know which filter is acting?

T. you.

Comment: `$scope.searchClient` contains what the user entered in the inputs. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, my doubt is which of these ng-model is being used to the query.
Exemple: user searches in the field ng-model="searchClient.name
How to know who angularJS  is using searchClient.name and not searchClient.cnpj for filtering?

Comment: He's using each of them, as long as they contain something. Read http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter : *Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1"*

Comment: I solved my problem by adding an event of 'focus', depending on the input I save a value in a variable to know which is being used.
I also clean what was typed in the other inputs so there are not two or more filters running at the same time.

thank all

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your problem correct. If you need to distinguish to find what is changed you can just use $watch under the specific property like this:

```
$scope.$watch('searchClient.name', function(val) {
});

$scope.$watch('searchClient.cnpj', function(val) {
});
```

But you need to keep in mind that if you make some heavy refresh when the filters are changed you may have too many requests when user is typing something. In this case we usually use debounce algorithm. It works like this (from documentation): "as long as it continues to be invoked, will not be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for N milliseconds."